# Nest.js asynchrony behaviour

Tags: async-await, nestjs

I don't clearly understand how works Nest.js asynchrony. For example if don't want my appliation block event loop then how i should work with this?

here is my controller

```
  @Get()
  async findAll() {
    return await this.templatesService.findAll();
 }
```

and here is my service

```
 async findAll() {
    return await this.templatesRepository.find();
 }
```

Does this 'await' block my application somehow? I mean can i do my requests to backend if this 'await' waiting response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of async/await is actually to prevent your application from freezing while handling requests. That means, you can send requests to your backend while the server is processing the previous one.

Comment: So my code example is ok for situation where i want my code to stay "alive" and still taking the requests?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you write your code using TS, then pay attention to declare types, such as:

`async findAll(): Promise<Template[]> { return await this.templatesService.findAll(); }`

Comment: Ok, does the same way it works in express?
""" app.get('/getAll',async (req, res) => {
      await fetchData()
      res.send();
} ""

Comment: Yes, that is plain JavaScript functionality.